# How to get the token by using Retrofit2?

Tags: android, token, retrofit2, yandex

The format of the response from the token

Yandeks.OAuth returns the token and the time of his life in a JSON-formatted:

```
200 OK
Content-type: application/json

{
  "access_token": "5fd980a5133b4887a8937fe07d3a0a60",
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "expires_in": 124234123534
}
```

**Interface OAuthServerIntf.class:**

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("authorize?response_type=token")
Call<OAuthTokenYandex> requestTokenForm1(
         @Field("client_id") String client_id
);
```

**But buider, that it is not so? error json**

```
@NonNull
    public static OAuthServerIntf yandexBuilder() {
        //Using Default HttpClient
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl("https://oauth.yandex.ru/")
                .build();
        OAuthServerIntf webServer = retrofit.create(OAuthServerIntf.class);
        return webServer;
    }
```

**logs:**

```
java.io.IOException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at path $
```

Comment: `addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())`

Comment: `java.io.IOException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at path $`

Comment: Dump/debug the response first to spot the problematic point that's most likely is not a JSON document.